# Python: Scraping ID's from JSON

Tags: python, json, list, filter, scrape

This question is a bit of an ask, but it's been giving me a headache all day (as I am fairly new to programming).

Basically I have huge list of ID's (named pk's) and I need to get all of them as they are surrounded by other text.

How would I go about retrieving all of the ID's? By the way each ID looks like this:

```
"pk":12345678
"pk":123456789
```

The ID is either a 8 or 9 digit number.

Thanks a lot guys, any help would be appreciated!

*Editor's note: Asker did post his [full json data](http://pastebin.com/CXNe2DCT) in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11459592/418413).*

Comment: You need to tell us more about the JSON format you have; and more importantly, what you have tried.

Comment: If you have the IDs in a file that looks like what you've posted, then you can do this: `IDs = [int(line.strip().split(":")) for line in open('filepath')]`. But as @MartijnPieters says, you need to post more if you want a more helpful answer

Comment: If you have the IDs in a file that looks like what you've posted, … then it's not JSON. If it *is* JSON, there's probably a very simple way to extract what you need.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the list? Something contains 10 ids should be enough.

Comment: It sounds as if you're trying to parse the data as plain text.  I'd suggest looking into the json library: http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ids = [var["pk"]]
```

where var is the variable of your JSON

If you clarify your JSON a little more I might be able to make this more precise.

Comment: I need to just iterate through the list. Then I have to remove every other id because every other id is a comment and not a user.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use [JSONPath](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath/). A simple, but extremely general way to extract all the `ids` would be this:

```
>>> from jsonpath import jsonpath
>>> from json import loads
>>> instagram_pop = open("instagram_popular_list.json"), "r").read()
>>> instagram_data = loads(instagram_pop)
>>> jsonpath(instagram_data, '$..id')[:3]
[u'234148392791340801_11305924', u'234098919041318605_2364270', u'234153616185741448_1907035']
```

Of course, since your data is flat, you can get away with a direct loop, such as:

```
[item['id'] for item in instagram_data['items']]
```

but I have a feeling you have more struct parsing to do, so I think jsonpath is a more flexible answer.

Comment: Little editorial note: The python jsonpath module doesn't actually parse a json *string*: It parses literal python data structures – the kind of data that you can get out of `json.loads(string)`.